# How to call php library installed on root with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I just installed composer on a VPS server and installed this library https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk everything seems to be ok. i believe the installation was successful too. Now that I want to use it in one of the cpanel accounts i have no clue how to call the php library so I can use it? i did some research but found nothing..

```
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

// Fill form with data array
$pdf = new Pdf('/full/path/to/form.pdf');
$pdf->fillForm(array(
    'name'=>'ÄÜÖ äüö мирано čárka',
    'nested.name' => 'valX',
))
->needAppearances()
->saveAs('filled.pdf');
```

This could should work but how do I include the mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf library so I can use it on one of the accounts?

Thank you

Comment: this is not really how this library should be installed, you will want to install the library in the cpanel accounts directory, using composer install, you will then require the `require ./vendor/autoload.php` in your above code ... you should really read the documentation

Comment: what should I do now? do I install on individual cpanel accounts?

Comment: Composer manages the dependencies on individual applications. So if the user of "a cpanel account" is able to upload an application by himself, he should be able to also install all dependencies with Composer. Don't use Composer to install stuff that should be used by everyone on the server - this is what PEAR did, and it didn't work out in the end, because you'd have a very hard time updating stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I managed to install it in the user's cpanel account. It is working fine now.